Wait for Platform Event is not pass when a new event is published
I trigger the flow below using Postman, and the Flow Interview is showing as "Paused" in the Flow.

Then, I publish a new platform event using Postman, and this event appears in Stream Monitoring.
However, the Flow Interview is still waiting. I am considering whether it's a permission issue with the Guest profile, so I have already granted read and create permissions for them, but it doesn't work.


If it appears in Stream Monitor, then it means event was successfully published from Postman, sfdc received it and received by client. There may be some issue with flow setup related to Platform Event.
